# Meteor method not found

Tags: meteor

I have public.js in the /server folder with this code:

```
Meteor.methods({
    foo: function (myarg) {
        return myarg;
    }
});
```

I am hooking a button click event in my template script like this:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
    'click #clickme' : function() {
        Meteor.call(foo, 'ola', function(error, result) {
            alert(result);
        });
    }
});
```

I can't see what is wrong here, as I get the message 'Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined' when clicking my button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Meteor.call('foo', ...)`, you need to pass the name of the function as a string.